# Convert nested object into Json Array of object

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I want to convert nested object in Json Array.
want to convert this below object

```
{
  "ErrorPage": {
    "PASS": 2
  },
  "Automated": {
    "PASS": 17,
    "FAIL": 31
  },
  "HomePage(Landing page)": {
    "PASS": 1,
    "FAIL": 6
  }
}
```

Into json array of object same as mention below

```
[
  { "category": "ErrorPage"
    "PASS": 2
  },
  {
    "category": "Automated" 
    "PASS": 17,
    "FAIL": 31
  },
  {
    "category": "HomePage(Landing page)" 
    "PASS": 1,
    "FAIL": 6
  }
]
```

I am doing this:

```
  this.httpService.getmoduleTest().subscribe((data) => {

      const res = data;
      this.Arr = Object.keys(res).map(key=>{
        return  {
          "category": key,
          "pass": res[key],
          "fail" : res[key]
        }
      }) 
      console.log(this.Arr);


    }
```

I don't know how to set pass and fail value in it.

Comment: you mean JSON.stringify(obj) ?

Comment: yes I want to make JSON array of object

Comment: In your implementation change `{"category": key,"pass": res[key],
          "fail" : res[key]}` to `{"category": key,...res[key]}`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `Object.entries` along with the function `map` as follow:

```js
let obj = {"ErrorPage": {"PASS": 2},"Automated": {"PASS": 17,"FAIL": 31},"HomePage(Landing page)": {"PASS": 1,"FAIL": 6}},
    result = Object.entries(obj).map(([category, v]) => ({category, ...v}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  input = {
    ErrorPage: {
      PASS: 2
    },
    Automated: {
      PASS: 17,
      FAIL: 31
    },
    "HomePage(Landing page)": {
      PASS: 1,
      FAIL: 6
    }
  };
  output = [];

  constructor() {
     this.output = Object.keys(this.input).map(category => ({
        ...this.input[category],
        category
     }));
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzbten?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: why chosing `closure [] and [].push` over `.map` ?

Comment: @AZ_Thanks for the suggesion

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "ErrorPage": {
    "PASS": 2
  },
  "Automated": {
    "PASS": 17,
    "FAIL": 31
  },
  "HomePage(Landing page)": {
    "PASS": 1,
    "FAIL": 6
  }
};

var arr= [];

Object.keys(jsonObj).map((item) => {
 arr.push({
   category: item,
    ...jsonObj[item]
  })
});

console.log(arr);
```